# Website to show my dynamic office hours

Tags: web-apps

I am looking for a web-app where I can show my dynamic office hours. I would place the link to this site on my e-mail footer. If somebody wants to see if I am in the office they could click the link and it will tell them if I'm in or not. Standard office hours would be 9-5, but if I work at home then I should be able to change this for that specific day and possibly also add a message.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Probably not, but it would be easy to write if you have basic web-programming skills.

Answer (score 2):

I have used https://youcanbook.me/ to that effect several times when I was overseas and had to significantly shift working hours. It has the added benefit of preventing overbooking.

Definitely worth experimenting with it as it is fairly intuitive and has a low learning curve, if any.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar as an embed calendar option, and you can even customize parts of it.  You can copy and paste the link for them to click on, or if your email client and your users client support html it should show up.

[image: Google Embeddable Calendar]